# Disable i2c in Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, i2c

I want to disable the i2c in raspberry pi, so that I can use it as GPIOs. I commented the lines in the /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf, but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the modules are loaded with `lsmod | grep i2c`.  If they are, they aren't in use, so you should be able to use `rmmod -v` or (better) `modprobe -rv` to unload them.

Comment: This is what I got when I gave ilsmod | grep i2c
2c_dev                 5557  0 
i2c_bcm2708             3997  0 
regmap_i2c              1645  1 snd_soc_core
Does this mean the i2c is enabled or disabled?

Comment: To understand that output better, try `lsmod` without `grep` so you can see the column headers.  Anyway, `i2c_dev` and `i2c_bcm2708` have 0 in the "Used by" column, so `modprobe -rv i2c_dev` and `modprobe -rv i2c_bcm2708` should work (`modprobe -r` -- **the `-r` is crucial** -- is like `rmmod` but more thorough in that it will also remove uneeded dependencies of what's removed).

Comment: This is what I got when i gave modprobe -rv i2c_dev

rmmod i2c_dev
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:753 kmod_module_remove_module: could not remove 'i2c_dev': Operation not permitted

Comment: Ah.  You need to be root or use `sudo`, I guess.

Comment: I did with sudo, but when I test those pins with an LED ( PIN 5 and 7-I2C pins), LED turns on when I power on Raspberry Pi. When I run a program to turn off the LED, it turned off, but whenever I power on the Pi, it will turn on automatically. If I use another GPIO pin (other than I2C), LED wont glow on power on.

Comment: You can add that `modprobe -r` stuff to `/etc/rc.local`. You don't need sudo there because it runs root during boot, but you do need to use complete absolute paths for commands because `$PATH` may not be set: so `/sbin/modprobe -r`.  If that's not good enough, I can explain how to move the modules out of `/lib/modules` so the kernel won't be able to find them -- of course, this is presuming that this is the kernel.  Have you watched the boot process on a monitor to see at what point the LED goes on?  If it happens *immediately* when you plug it in, there's a more complex mystery to solve ;)

Comment: The LED glows immediately when the Pi is turned on. 
Is disabling i2c that much difficult? Enabling was very easy.
Will adding modprobe -r i2c_dev and i2c_bcm2708 to /etc/re.local, solve this issue. I am new to Pi, don't know much about these things.

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` runs at the end of the boot process, which is why it should work to unload the modules after the kernel has detected the hardware and loaded them.  However, the whole boot process is 20+ seconds.  If that LED comes on as soon as you plug the power in without any delay at all, then it has nothing to do with the OS, etc, and there's probably nothing you can do to stop that.

Comment: So, can't I use the i2c pins as GPIO?? Is there some other reason why this happens??

Comment: AFAIK you can; there are 17 GPIO pins and that includes the ones used for I2C.  I only use I2C, so I don't know details beyond that.  But if you unload or render inaccessible the i2c modules, they should be available to you.  *Have you tried to use them?*  The fact that the LED lights up when the power plugs in does not mean you can't do anything with those pins from then on -- obviously you can, since the I2C interface is software and it uses those pins...

Comment: ...you did say earlier you can turn the LED off programmatically, so I'm confused as to what the problem is.  Obviously you can't use them until the system is booted, no, and that does take at least 20 seconds.  If there's more to this, you can always ask another *more detailed* question about *how* to use the GPIO -- I don't know about that, but I do know how to disable I2C.

Comment: LEDs is turned off according to the delay I mention, after that it will turn on again automatically unless I give LED off within an infinite loop. Thanks for your input. I will post a detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

This has done the exact opposite - it has enabled the i2c, which is disabled by default.

PS The i2c pins have on-board pull-up resistors.

Comment: Oh sorry, I uncommented it for enabling i2c and now I commented it. I now edited my question. Thanks for pointing it out